# Injective/one-to-one functions, what are they how do they work?

Tags: functions

I've just run into injective functions and having never seen them, I am quite unsure what they are for and how to use them, a simple explanation of injective functions is preferable

the function f: A → B is injective/one-to-one if f(x) = f(y), for some x,y ∈ A

Which I think equates to something similar to ∀x,y ∈ A f(x) = f(y) → x = y. So for the following 2 examples, how would I show if they are injective or not?

f: Z → Z given by f(x) = 3x + 7

f which maps a staff ID to the last name of a staff member with that ID.

Comment: First, I don't think your first definition is true/makes sense and is missing a bit of information. I'm not sure where you got it from. The second definition you gave is the one commonly used as far as I'm aware. Now, to show the first function is injective $$f(x) = f(y) \implies 3x + 7 = 3y + 7 \implies 3(x-y) = 0 \implies ?$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'as $x$ and $y$ equate to each other'. You are trying to _prove_ that $x$ and $y$ are the same value, you don't _assume_ it. Just so we're clear, the definition of injectivity says $$f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$$ (notice the implication symbol $\implies$). Following my reasoning above, we find $$3(x-y) = 0 \implies x-y = 0 \implies x = y$$ and hence, for our function, _because_ $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$, _then_ our function is injective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original definition is not quite true, but your second reformulation is.

A function $f: A \rightarrow B$ is injective if, $$\forall x,y \in A, f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$$

I think it’s easier, at least conceptually, to think about the contrapositive, which is equivalent. $f$ is injective if
$$\forall x,y \in A, x\neq y \Rightarrow f(x)\neq f(y)$$

So the idea here is that if you take any 2 distinct elements in the set, and they never map to the same value, then your function is injective. I like to think of it like you’re not really “losing information” when you have a function that’s injective. For example, if I said let $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, this is most definitely not injective, and there’s a loss of information. If I told you that I plugged some value into $g$ and got $0$, you’d have no idea what my original number is. However, injective functions preserve some uniqueness because at most one element maps to any given output.

So let’s consider your second example with the staff IDs. Do we lose information here by mapping last names to IDs? In other words, if I said someone’s staff ID was 1234 (assuming it’s a valid ID number), would you be able to uniquely identify the person? Or is it possible for multiple staff members to have an ID of 1234?

Similarly, if I plug in an integer $x$ to $f$ and get an output,would you be able to uniquely identify the number I inputted? If this value is unique, how might you express what it is?

This property of “uniqueness” is injectivity.

**Edit:** In regards to the ID question, it really depends on what the question is really asking. You have to consider what the domain of the mapping is.

Say we had a map that took people to IDs. And we had that anyone with the same surname has the same ID.

Then we would have something like:

```
John Smith->1
Jane Johnson->2
Sam Smith->1
```

In this case, it would **not** be injective, because if I were to say, "which person has ID #1, there's no unique answer (both Sam and John have the same ID).

However, consider the case of a mapping from *surnames* (rather than people / full names) to IDs.

```
Smith->1
Johnson->2
Doe->3
```

In this case, the mapping would be injective, since for any given ID, I can recover the unique surname associated with it. This hints at an important fact: by change the domain, it's sometimes possible to make functions injective that weren't originally.

Comment: with the second one, although an ID would usually be injective (to what I understand), the example is not as it links a surname to an ID, and assuming the staff examples are

John Smith, Mike Johnson, Sam Smith

both John and Sam would be linked to the same ID, no longer making it injective, as John would get ID x, Mike ID y, but then as Sam has same last name as John, would also get ID x?

Unless I got something wrong and it is actually injective, just creating a new ID under the same name `1 : Smith, 2: Johnson, 3: Smith etc..`

Comment: @Anan ah, you bring up a valid point. I have edited my response—see if that answers the question.

Comment: Using **Map a staff ID to the last name of a staff member with that ID.**

So, in this case, the ID is mapped to the last name of a staff member. So `ID 1 : Name x, ID 2 : Name y, ID 3 : Name x/Name z` _(where z=x)_ would be the output (i think), but still not sure if it would create a new node (`Name z`(keeping it injective)) which the ID would link to, or simply link to the same node (`Name x`(no longer injective)) with same value.

Comment: Yes this changes the question then because you're doing the reverse mapping (ID to name rather than the reverse). In this case, remember that a function is defined to only have one output, so you can't have ID 3, for example, be associated with John Smith and Sam Smith. So now there's a different problem. If you have ID 1 mapping to John Smith and ID 3 mapping to Sam Smith, then if I said "hey, what ID is associated with last name Smith?" You can't give me a unique answer.

Comment: so it follows `ID 1 : Name x, ID 2 : Name y, ID 3 : Name x` and in fact not injective as cannot have Name z where z=x

Comment: @Anan correct. If there's a possibility for multiple people with the same surname, then you can't uniquely pick out an ID based on a surname.

Comment: cool, thanks for all the help! Drawing a little diagram also makes things easier